# Python, virtualenv: Getting permission error while activating

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have been given a laptop. So I copied from my Work PC `.virtualenvs/` directory to my NAS and then I copied it back to my new laptop.

I installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` but I can't get my virtual environment to work. This is what I got at first:

```
chris@chris-amilo ~ $ workon iwidget
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/preactivate": [Errno 13] Permission denied
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/iwidget/bin/preactivate": [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

then I did a chmod +x to those files. Although I could change to this environment after, no library can be seen.

I also get this:

```
chris@chris-amilo ~ $ ./.virtualenvs/iwidget/bin/activate
bash: ./.virtualenvs/iwidget/bin/activate: Permission denied
```

Also, the following shows that although I can `workon` on certain env, nothing can be imported: (after I did a chmod +x to preactivate files)

```
chris@chris-amilo ~ $ workon iwidget
(iwidget)chris@chris-amilo ~ $ python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pytz
>>> 
(iwidget)chris@chris-amilo ~ $ ls .virtualenvs/iwidget/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py
py4j/                               pytz/
py4j-0.8.1-py2.7.egg-info/          pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg-info/
python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg-info/
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check owner/group and `chown` if necessary

Comment: I use the same username to both machines. So owner/group are the same in both machines.

Comment: The "permission denied" error nevertheless indicates a permission problem. Does `chmod +r` help? That's the permission you need to source the `activate` script and for Python to read the libraries.

Comment: If you have the same user name but a different numeric user ID, that could cause a problem, depending also on how exactly you transferred the files.

Comment: Hum, the first line in activate says:  
`# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly`
could this not be your problem?, i.e. you need to **source** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving virtualenvs is tricky. It's a much better bet to rebuild them from scratch on the new machine. If you're using a requirements file, this is trivial: just do `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If you're not using one, create it on the old machine with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Comment: this was about to be my last resort. So I can't pip freeze into my new machine. it has to be in my old machine, only?

Comment: Yes, the whole point is that it lists what you have installed right now.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you have no execute (run) privileges on those scripts. I had a similar problem, but only for the .virtualenvs/preactivate file.

`chmod u+x ~/.virtualenvs/*`

did the trick for me, but I see it's also noted in your answer. Its got maybe something to do with migrating your virtualenvs from a different machine?

You probably need to do the same thing for ~/.virtualenvs/iwidget/bin/*

Using virtualenvwrapper, you don't need to use the activate script in the folder itself, but if you wanted to do this, you would have to invoke the command like this:

`. .virtualenvs/iwidget/bin/activate`

Note the dot in front of it? That dot is actually a command, albeit very easily overlooked, and it is used to activate an env; the activate script can't be run on it's own, as the first two lines of the file will tell you. The command `source` is an alias for the dot.

But `workon iwidget` should take care of all that jazz.

As for the import problem, you might want to run `pip install pytz` within your env, before trying to import it. To see if it is in your env, type: `pip freeze|grep pytz`.